# Serializing ConcurrentQueue using protobuf

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize a ConcurrentQueue using protobuf , but i am getting an exception when i am deserializing the object

```
Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[[System.Byte[], mscorlib
```

is there a way to solve it? like writing extension to Protobuf or inheriting and extending ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: Why would you need to serialize a concurrent queue? Dequeue the items and use say `List<T>` or array. You can repopulate the actual queue after you deserialize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer of protobuf has stated [here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=354) that `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is not supported and gives a workaround similar to Lloyd's suggestion. Adding the code below in case the link is no longer available:

```
public ConcurrentQueue<int> Items {get;set;}

[ProtoMember(n)]
private int[] Items
{
    get { return Items.ToArray(); }
    set { Items = new ConcurrentQueue<int>(value); }
}
```